# Issue with segment glyph GMapPlot overlay - bokeh 0.10.0

Tags: python, google-maps, overlay, bokeh

I'm having an issue with a script I wrote a few months ago which used to successfully overlay segments onto GMapPlots. The script hasn't changed since and was verified working before (in 0.9.3 I believe.).

That example is too verbose to include here, but my problem can be illustrated using the bokeh/examples/glyphs/maps.py example. Modifying that script to use a GMapPlot fails to overlay for segment glyphs, but it works fine for the rest. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
from __future__ import print_function

from bokeh.browserlib import view
from bokeh.document import Document
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Circle
from bokeh.models import (
    GMapPlot, DataRange1d, ColumnDataSource,
    PanTool, WheelZoomTool, BoxSelectTool,
    BoxSelectionOverlay, GMapOptions, Segment, Ray)
from bokeh.resources import INLINE

# JSON style string taken from: https://snazzymaps.com/style/1/pale-dawn
map_options = GMapOptions(lat=30.2861, lng=-97.7394, map_type="roadmap", zoom=13, styles="""
[{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":33}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2e5d4"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#c5dac6"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#c5c6c6"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e4d7c6"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#fbfaf7"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#acbcc9"}]}]
""")

xdr = DataRange1d()
ydr = DataRange1d()
```

Now if I call the following plot and continue the script below, it produces a plot with the three circles and segments connecting them:

```
# ADDING SEGMENTS TO THIS PLOT WORKS
plot = Plot(
    title=None, x_range=xdr, y_range=ydr, plot_width=300, plot_height=300,
    h_symmetry=False, v_symmetry=False, min_border=0, toolbar_location=None)
```

However if I use the following GMapPlot the segment glyphs do not appear, only the circle glyphs:

```
# ADDING SEGMENTS TO THIS PLOT DOES NOT WORK
plot = GMapPlot(x_range=xdr, y_range=ydr, map_options=map_options, title="Austin")
```

Rest of script:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        lat=[30.2861, 30.2855, 30.2869],
        lon=[-97.7394, -97.7390, -97.7405],
        fill=['orange', 'blue', 'green']
    )
)

segdata = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        lonend=[-97.7390,-97.7405],
        lonstart=[-97.7394,-97.7390],
        latend=[30.2855,30.2869],
        latstart=[30.2861,30.2855]
    )
)

segment = Segment(x0='lonstart',y0='latstart',x1='lonend',y1='latend',line_color="firebrick",line_width=5)
plot.add_glyph(segdata, segment)

circle = Circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=10, fill_color="fill", line_color="black")
plot.add_glyph(source, circle)

pan = PanTool()
wheel_zoom = WheelZoomTool()
box_select = BoxSelectTool()

plot.add_tools(pan, wheel_zoom, box_select)
overlay = BoxSelectionOverlay(tool=box_select)
plot.add_layout(overlay)

doc = Document()
doc.add(plot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "maps.html"
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(file_html(doc, INLINE, "Google Maps Example"))
    print("Wrote %s" % filename)
    view(filename)
```

[Plot with Plot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNvne.png)

[Plot with GMapPlot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYwHQ.png)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Cause I'm seeing the same issue